# LibGDX getKeyFrame said to return object instead of TextureRegion/frame

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fJrhgc0RRw

I am getting "Gradle error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to TextureRegion"

at this line:

`region = heroJump.getKeyFrame(stateTimer);`

heroJump is declared as:

```
private Animation heroJump;
```

and that is imported up top as:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
```

In Android Studio the flyout box when you type heroJump.getKeyFrame() shows that Object is the return type of the function.
In the tutorial it shows a TexturedFrame.
I'm importing it the same as the tutorial.
I'm not sure why it doesn't see the return type as the same thing.
Even when I click the Animation class to view its docs it appears to come up with the proper return types.

What is not being done correctly so that AndroidStudio/Compiler knows the correct return type and will compile?

Comment: The Animation class was changed recently, see: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3980. If you follow a tutorial then make sure to use the libgdx version that was used to create the tutorial.

Comment: Simplest answer is change 
"private Animation heroJump;" 
to  
"private Animation<TextureRegion> heroJump;"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method is declared in the API as

```
public T getKeyFrame(float stateTime)
```

And the class definition `public class Animation<T>`.

You have a raw `Animation` instance. The import isn't the problem. The declaration is.

For example, you'd want `private Animation<TextureRegion> heroJump;` and you'd give that your `Array<TextureRegion>`

Comment: This works. Thank you.  Still do not understand why the tutorial does not need that in their declaration though.  Perhaps its changed over time.

Comment: Probably changed considering the autocomplete that appeared in the video did show the array parameter was needing to be a `TextureRegion` collection

Comment: The class was changed in the 1.9.5 LibGDX release, so the tutorial is likely outdated.

Answer (score 4):

You're not defining the generics in a way that the compiler can un-ambiguously determine them. `Animation` is actually an `Animation<T>` where T needs to be specified to the compiler. The 'fix' is to define T in your heroJump instance so if it's expected to be a TextureRegion then it would need to be set to:

```
private Animation<TextureRegion> heroJump;
```

Rather than the ambiguous form you listed in your codeblock.

Comment: Thank you, would mark as anwser but you were beaten by a few seconds :)

Comment: @ChrisValentine - not a problem :D